# Scrolling effect on menu items

Tags: jquery, css

My HTML code has a long menu. I want to display only the first five menu items to the user. The rest of the items will be displayed on (mouse) hover effect.

```
<ul id="slider">
   <li>Menu Content 1</li>
   <li>Menu Content 2</li>
   <li>Menu Content 3</li>
   <li>Menu Content 4</li>
   <li>Menu Content 5</li>
   <li>Menu Content 6</li>
   <li>Menu Content 7</li>
   <li>Menu Content 8</li>
   <li>Menu Content 9</li>
   <li>Menu Content 10</li>
   <li>Menu Content 12</li>
   <li>Menu Content 13</li>
   <li>Menu Content 14</li>
   <li>Menu Content 15</li>
   <li>Menu Content 16</li>
</ul>
```

I want something like this :-

http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/

**"Kinda Tall Menu"**

I tried several solutions but they did not work for me.

Comment: What approaches did you try?

Comment: An example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help us a lot.

Comment: When you say scrolling do you mean you want the element to stay the same size - so only ever show 5 items but allow the user to scroll? In which case look at CSS Overflow

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 5;
$('li').slice(n).hide();

$( "li" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $('li').show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('li').slice(n).hide();
});
```

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4J4e4/

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide all of the li you don't want visible initially (I did this by adding them all to a class, 'hide'). Then, when you mouseover the menu, it will slide those li down, and mouseleave will slide them back up.

HTML

```
<ul id="slider">
<li>Menu Content 1</li>
<li>Menu Content 2</li>
<li>Menu Content 3</li>
<li>Menu Content 4</li>
<li>Menu Content 5</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 6</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 7</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 8</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 9</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 10</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 12</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 13</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 14</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 15</li>
<li class="hide">Menu Content 16</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$("#slider").on("mouseover",function(){
$("li.hide").slideDown();
});

$("#slider").on("mouseleave",function(){
$("li.hide").stop(true,true).slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tpqg7/1/

Comment: @LuckyBoy what do you mean by "scrolling effect"? That's a pretty vague request.

Comment: @LuckyBoy You can just view the source of the example then.. they are using this to create the dropdwown http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/js/jquery.dropdown.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without javascript.
Here is the css:

```
#slider li{
    display:none;
}
#slider li:first-child,
#slider li:first-child+li,
#slider li:first-child+li+li,
#slider li:first-child+li+li+li,
#slider li:first-child+li+li+li+li{
    display:block;
}
#slider:hover li{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... or check **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPmYL/) ...** I have apply my logic on `mousehover`. at a time only `three <li>` display.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('li').bind('mouseenter', function () {
                if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none') {
                    $(this).next().css('display', '');
                    $(this).prev().css('display', '');
                    $(this).prev().prev().css('display', 'none');
                    $(this).next().next().css('display', 'none');
                }
                else if ($(this).prev().css('display') == 'none') {
                    $(this).next().css('display', '');
                    $(this).prev().css('display', '');
                    $(this).next().next().css('display', 'none');
                    $(this).prev().prev().css('display', 'none');

                }
            });
        });

        function Apply() {
            var i = 0;
            $('li').each(function () {
                if (i > 2) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                }
                i = i + 1;
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Apply()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div >
        <ul id="slider">
            <li>Menu Content 1</li>
            <li>Menu Content 2</li>
            <li>Menu Content 3</li>
            <li>Menu Content 4</li>
            <li>Menu Content 5</li>
            <li>Menu Content 6</li>
            <li>Menu Content 7</li>
            <li>Menu Content 8</li>
            <li>Menu Content 9</li>
            <li>Menu Content 10</li>
            <li>Menu Content 12</li>
            <li>Menu Content 13</li>
            <li>Menu Content 14</li>
            <li>Menu Content 15</li>
            <li>Menu Content 16</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.....

Comment: @LuckyBoy Could you please let me know is it fine with you or not...?